# Pandas DataFrame add Seriers Has Wrong Value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame B
The Last Several Value Are

```
2014-09-22  0.263394   1.460577
2014-09-23  0.274304   1.455913
2014-09-24  0.296823   1.466214
2014-09-25  0.294221   1.473936
2014-09-26  0.294346   1.457969
2014-09-29  0.299975   1.459628
2014-09-30  0.301668   1.459297
```

And a Series A
The Last Several Value Are

```
2014-09-01    0.220297
2014-09-02    0.220492
2014-09-04    0.220668
2014-09-05    0.220873
2014-09-10    0.221093
2014-09-16    0.221278
2014-09-18    0.221616
2014-09-19    0.221772
2014-09-26    0.222129

B['A']=A

2014-09-16  0.268623   1.418165  0.221278
2014-09-17  0.275294   1.424700       NaN
2014-09-18  0.279191   1.424473  0.221616
2014-09-19  0.287979   1.423771  *0.221772*
2014-09-22  0.263394   1.460577  *0.215401*
2014-09-23  0.274304   1.455913  *0.215581*
2014-09-24  0.296823   1.466214  *0.216043*
2014-09-25  0.294221   1.473936  *0.216869*
2014-09-26  0.294346   1.457969  0.222129
2014-09-29  0.299975   1.459628  *0.217745*
2014-09-30  0.301668   1.459297  *0.218038*
```

You See  2014-09-17 the value is NaN.
but other day it has a value ex: 2014-09-30 the Value is 0.218038 
Why this will happen?
Why this is not NA?

I try reindex.but get error

```
A.reindex(B.index,method='pad')
ValueError: Must be monotonic for forward fill
```

Comment: What does `A["2014-09-30"]` return?  Probably A has a value for that day, but A is out of order and so you don't see it when you look at the end.

Comment: What happens when you do this: B['A'] = np.nan. B.ix[A.index, 'A'] = A?